# Asking remotely a computer to wake another via WOL

Tags: networking, ssh, wakeonlan

I understand Wake-on-LAN cannot work if you're trying to wake a computer from outside the network, however, on a very far observatory, there's this server running on Ubuntu shutting off automatically on bad weather, so we want to wake it remotely over the WAN.

There are lots of computers there which I can connect via ssh, and are also on the same network as the aforementioned server.

My question is, How can I ask one of those computers to send a WoL command to server that is down?

Comment: You may instead want to investigate why the server is shutting down to begin with so that you can prevent that from happening at all.

Comment: Voting to reopen, this question is definitely not _specific_ to the mentioned EOL release.

Comment: I agree with @Melebius: **regardless of the Ubuntu version, this is still a valid question today...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy-peasy:

1. Hike up to the remote observatory and turn on the Wake-On-Lan in the BIOS or on the NIC card if needed. write down the MAC address.
2. SSH into any other machine and type:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install wakeonlan
    wol MA:CA:DD:RE:SS
   ```

   where `MA:CA:DD:RE:SS` is the MAC address of your server.

#### Done!